# CKfinder for Ckeditor (PHP) returns errors

Tags: php, upload, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm trying to integrate an uploader to Ckeditor and I chose Ckfinder as it seemed to be the most documented. Not enough in my opinion as I've been struggling the whole day without being able to upload a single file. I also checked Stackoverflow and couldn't find recent and accurate answer to my problem.

So I installed it in my /js folder. The structure is as below :

```
root
  |__/js__
         |_/ckeditor
                   |_config.js
                   |_...
         |_/ckfinder
                   |_config.php
                   |_...
  |_/images__
             |/upload
  |_form.php
```

I integrated it that way based on the documentation and various tutorials.

```
<textarea id="ckeditor1"></textarea>
<script>
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor1', {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'js/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
    });
CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
</script>
```

Ckeditor and Ckfinder tools appear correctly but when I try to upload a file I receive an error "Server response is incorrect". Opening the server browser returns this :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$value' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/yatacrea/yelofox-test/js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/functions.php on line 36
```

I didn't alter the original code except for the 'baseUrl' from config.php that I set to my needs.

```
'baseUrl'      => '/images/upload/',
```

I'm pretty sure it's only a problem of path but couldn't figure out where was my mistake. Can you try and help me with this, please ?

Comment: What PHP version it's running on?

Comment: PHP 5.6 on a FTP server

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As I was think it was a mistake in the paths. I made a confusion between relative and absolute paths in config.php. It's ok now :)